# Web service exception handling with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, exception, wsdl

What is the best way to handle a custom exception with a web service created automatically with eclipse built-in plugin (new web service bottom up from a class)? 
if i define a method that throws a custom exception, the relative web service works fine. But if i create the relative web service client with eclipse, i will get an exception during the wsdl parsing

> Exception occurred during code generation for WSDL  : org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: org.apache.axis2.wsdl.codegen.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Element QName is null for ProjectNameCustomExceptionName!

the wsdl is generated automatically by eclipse, i think there are no errors.

Comment: Try this : 
[Creating Bottom Up Web Service via Apache Axis2](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BottomUpAxis2WebService/bu_tutorial.html)

Comment: i follow this guide, but there isn't any reference to exception handling